# Check, Is Exe file a SFX (Self-extracting archives) with WinRAR command line?

Tags: command-line, winrar

I want to check is a SFX (Self-extracting archives) file or not?
Is it possible to check it with command line of WinRar?

Comment: I don't know about `WinRar`, but you certainly can with 7-Zip: `7z t File.exe`. The command returns 0 for an archive and 2 if not. I don't know what is returned for a corrupt archive, but I guess in might be 1.

Answer (score 1):

use the command:

```
rar t mySFX.exe
```

if it returns **"All OK"** then it's an SFX

if it returns **"No files to extract"** then it's a non-SFX executable.

Here's the full command with the conditions.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('rar t mySFX.exe') DO set isSFX=%%i
IF /I "%isSFX%"=="All OK" echo It's an SFX
IF /I NOT "%isSFX%"=="All OK" echo It's NOT an SFX
```

remember to use %i instead if you're executing from a cmd window and not a bat file.